# How to typeset ``...(e.g. Equation 6)` using cleveref?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, parentheses

I use the `cleveref` package to produce equation references like `Figure 3` and `Equation (12)`. The parentheses for equation references are fine most of the time, but it seems silly when the reference is already enclosed by parentheses.

When I use `...(e.g. \Cref{eqn:ExampleEqn})`, it typesets it as `...(e.g. Equation (6))`. What I want is it to look like `...(e.g. Equation 6)`.

I know `\citep{}` has the ability to typeset citations differently: `\citep[e.g.][]{Author2019}` produces (at least, using the Elsevier author-year citation style) `(e.g. Author, 2019)`. I'm hoping for something like this with `cleveref`.

**Does `cleveref` have a "clever" way to reference things inside parentheses so that it doesn't add the extra set of parentheses?** If so, how? If not, what is a good way to do that for this one time (similar SX questions have answers that generally are for the entire document)?

Comment: are you sure you really want that? it sticks out to me as inconsistent; I personally prefer to typeset with square brackets for equations `[Eqn. (6)]`. That's the way aps journals do it as well, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Will there always be just one equation number to cross-reference in this parenthetic manner? Or might there be instances of the type `(e.g., Equations 4, 5, and 7)`?

Answer (score 1):

Make the parentheses to be inserted by macros which you can redefine at will.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{equation}{Equation~\textup{\OPEN#2#1#3\CLOSE}}
\newcommand{\OPEN}{(}
\newcommand{\CLOSE}{)}
\newcommand{\tcref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\OPEN}{}%
  \renewcommand{\CLOSE}{}%
  \cref{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a=b \label{test}
\end{equation}

\cref{test}

\tcref{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]